# "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource" and "java.lang.AbstractMethodError"

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I was going to use Hibernate with Elastic Search and following video on youtube.([Elasticsearch + Hibernate: from artisanal to industrial integration by Emmanuel Bernard/David Pilato](http://Elasticsearch%20+%20Hibernate:%20from%20artisanal%20to%20industrial%20integration%20by%20Emmanuel%20Bernard/David%20Pilato)).Before starting implementation of elastic search, It was working properly.

After changing configuration, I found error. I believe that I have hibernate version issues. Not sure. Let me know if you need any other information.

Thank you so much.

**Error**

```
Aug 02, 2017 11:48:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:621)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1835)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:307)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1799)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:900)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
... 25 more
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.19.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0.Beta3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/project" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="autotekcarparts" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<context:annotation-config />

<tx:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="project.model" />

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
         <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
        users-by-username-query="select email as username,password,'true' from users where email=?"
        authorities-by-username-query="select u.email as username, a.role as authority from users u left join authorities a on
         u.email = ? and u.id = a.user_id" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

 <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

<security:form-login login-page="/login.html"
    default-target-url="/Security.html" username-parameter="username"
    authentication-failure-url="/login.html" password-parameter="password"/>
</security:http>

 <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="autotekcarparts" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/project" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />

        <!-- Elastic Search -->
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexmanager" value="elasticsearch"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.host" value="http://127.0.0.1:9200"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.index_schema_management_strategy" value="CREATE"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 0):

The artifacts *hibernate-search-elasticsearch* and *hibernate-search-orm* are parts of the same distribution (**Hibernate Search**) so should always have exactly the same version.

The artifact *hibernate-entitymanager* is part of the **Hibernate ORM** distribution so that can be different but you should really pick a version of Hibernate Search and Hibernate ORM compatible with each other.

Since Hibernate ORM is the main project and is released first, the compatibility is documented in the Hibernate Search project.

See also the tables published here:
 http://hibernate.org/search/downloads/

I would recommend these versions:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The specific exception you have is indeed caused by mistmatching dependencies. In particular it's caused by having the wrong version of the JPA API on classpath: make sure to exclude unrelated dependencies bringing it in as the above Hibernate artifacts depend on the right version already.